# WinUI3 WindowsApp State Management

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, .net-7.0, windows-app-sdk

I'm looking to create state management for a Windows App desktop. It seems when going to back and forth from pages, the controls don't maintain their values. Do I have to cache the controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [NavigationCacheMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode?view=winrt-22621) to `Required` in pages that you want them to be cached while navigation.

```xml
<Page
  ...
  NavigationCacheMode="Required"
  ...
/>
```